# Origin of Reform/Conservative "scarf" talleisim

Tags: history, tallit-gadol, provenance, size, reform-judaism

I've noticed that Reform and Conservative often use small "scarf" talleisim ([here's an image](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/390522505598?lpid=82)). Where did this practice originate? (Is there any connection to the scarves that some Christian priests wear, and if so, could there be an issue of chukas hagoyim)? Is there some ideological reason why Reform and Conservative continue using "scarf" talleisim b'davka, or is it just something that they are used to doing for historical reasons?

Comment: The "scarf" tallit is not related to Reform or Conservative Judaism specifically. I know a lot of conservative and reform Jews (especially the rabbis!) who wear a "larger" tallit gadol. It actually arises from the German Jews, not a specific movement.

Comment: @Jason – Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Jason, in Reform and Conservative congregations they are used as standard today, whereas they are exceedingly rare in Orthodox congregations among those who own their own, and the synagogues themselves generally have the larger size only (for general use) on hand. The question seeks their origin, not their affiliation. Their affiliation today is Reform and Conservative (and perhaps others, but those being the largest movements, and both being movements where these are a common feature, I think the question is appropriate. However, with a source, you've got a valid answer.

Comment: Here is an interesting article on Jewish and non-Jewish liturgical garments, though it doesn't directly answer the question. See especially the paragraph beginning with "Ministerial vestments are sometimes called chukkat ha-goy, gentile usage." http://www.oztorah.com/2012/03/robes-the-rabbis/

Comment: From the shulchan aruch orach chayim siman 10 siff 11 and siman 301 siff 30 and relevant commentaries, one does not fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzis with a taalis worn as a scarf. The item you linked to is not even anywhere close to being in the discussion for a mitzvah as it actually has no tzitzis on it! The one saving grace is it a synthetic cloth so acc to Reb Moshe it does not require tzitzis and whoever wears it is not mivatel any mitzvah.

Comment: @user6591 "saving grace" ??? If it's too small or worn wrong they aren't mevatel anything either...

Comment: @Double AA true. But it seems big enough and someone might accidentally wear it right:)

Comment: I recently read that this is the Spanish-Portuguese minhag. They would wear a very long, relatively narrow tallit (or *tallet*, in SP parlance) in the manner now seen in Conservative/Reform schuls.

Comment: FWIW, my husband inherited a small talit like this from his (eastern-European) Orthodox grandfather, who never had anything to do with the Reform or Conservative movements or, *chas v'shalom*, Christianity.  My husband doesn't know its history, beyond that his grandfather used it his entire life (it wasn't just for a small bar-mitzvah child, in other words).

Comment: @MonicaCellio - It could have been a bar mitzvah tallis. I would say it was fairly common for Orthodox bar mitzvah boys to wear a small tallis and older married men to wear a large normal tallis. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuPovuR3wq5rhpguOOawhzxvMWg-J7obq2sI4toEbNUzlt-mno

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/londonsephardiminhag/tallet), which I received in an answer to a question about Spanish-Portuguese minhagim, the "scarf-like" tallit (or *tallet*) is originally from their community. As you can see below, the ba'alei battim, the chazzan, and the chacham all wear the style in question.

[image: S&P bringing Sifrei Torah to Teba]

Comment: They look much larger than the standard scarf talleisim. They seem to cover the whole back above the waist

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, people were shorter then. Furthermore, these are probably the size 24 affairs. Also, we mustn't forget that silk is significantly more pliable than our traditional wool.

Comment: Chas vishalom!  These taaleisim are fine even according to the Mishna Berurah. They are draped over the body, not just the neck. The issue is not so much size as it is the way it is worn. These are fine and have nothing to do with scarves.

Comment: @user6591, they don't fulfill the Mechaber's requirement that there be two corners in front and two behind though! I know this from personal experience, having tried on such a tallis.

Comment: I was not aware that suggestion of the mechaber is taken so seriously as to cause someone to lose their mitzvah by wearing it that way. In fact many many sfardi communities wear their taaleisim as pictured here!

Comment: @user6591, I was not aware that this was still the case. Anyway, the Rama is said to have disagreed, although unless this is in the Darchei Moshe, it has been removed from the TR of the Sh"A.

Comment: I think you might be confusing two sources. In siman 8 siff 4 tree shulchan aruch suggests to hand two corners in front and two in back. This is concerning a regular normal taalis and this suggestion when not heeded does not cause someone to have lost his mitzvah to the best of my knowledge. The other source, which I think you are referencing now is siman 10 siff 12 discussing jackets where the two corners found by the collar, and the two by the waist are under scrutiny. Both the beis yosef and ramma wonder why people don't put tzitzis on them, But both still rule that we should not. Cont.>

Comment: In the end the Darkei Moshe as brought in the Mishna Berurah says the reason we don't is because lichatchila one should be wearing two in front and two in back and since these types of clothing are impossible to ever wear the proper way lichatchila, we rule they are actually completely patur. But this is in stark contrast to a beged which can be worn in the proper lichatchila way, But for whatever reason isn't. This begged, I.e. the taaleisim in your picture, are chayav in tzitzis and one does fulfill the mitzvah even when worn with all for in front, being that it is possible to have 2x2.

Comment: @Noach I forgot to ping you. not sure if you got those last ones or not. ^^^^^^

Comment: @user6591, since this is my answer, I am automatically pinged for all comments

Comment: K:) That's what I thought but after writing all that I just wanted to double check to make sure it was actually seen:)

Comment: @user6591, don't worry, I saw it, I just didn't put a reply up.

Comment: @Noach An addition to our discussion. In Cesser Rosh, the author states the Villa Goan only kissed the front two tzitzis during krias shema as he didn't want to bring the rear ones to the front since the halcha as brought in the Shulchan Aruch states to have two in the front and two in the back.

Comment: @user6591, I've heard that in the name of the Gr"a as well

Comment: Yeah. I knew he only kissed the front two. I wasn't aware of the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers indicate, the scarf way to wear it happened in certain other communities as other times. I haven't seen any point of connection between the modern practice and these isolated instances. The most likely origin of the Ashkenazi Reform/Conservative way of wearing it as a scarf is the imitation of the Christian [Stole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stole_%28vestment%29). The Reform synagogue, in an effort to assimilate, copied many of the features of Protestant Church. Rabbis would, and still do in many synagogues, wear [Clerical Robes](https://www.faithandleadership.com/sites/default/files/styles/article/public/field/image/geneva-robe_tp_0.jpg?itok=gtFKfRWG) and fold their tallith to resemble a stole so they could closer resemble a Protestant Minister. Add in a choir, organ, and vernacular services, and superficially, an early reform service would have been hard to differentiate from a German Protestant church service. My best guess for why it became widespread is that congregants would see their rabbis wearing the tallith in such a manner, and copy it.

Answer (score 0):

from what I have heard the original reform movement made change in in davening both the liturgy and the dress of those leading to be more like the church. This was part of their goal to become assimilated and then so they thought become more accepted by non-Jews. Today I don't think this people today use this tallis for this reason but rather after several generations it simply became popular. The main problems with such tallesim... 1)they often aren't big enough to require tzitzis. 2)even if they are large enough wearing them in such a manner is problematic as each of the tzitzis are to be on the four corners around one's body and not all in the front.

Answer (score 0):

i can't speak to its exact origins, but it seems to have been a well established practice by many Jewish communities scattered all over the world. This is the official Halacha of Egyptian Jews regarding Tallitoth.

> Nehar Misrayim Chapter 1:
>
> במצרים רובא דרובא דהמוני עם משלשלין כל הארבעה ציציות לצד פניהם והטלית
>   מקופל על צוארם וראוי להודיעם שלפחות בשערת העטיפה. יברך ויתעטף בו ראשו
>   ורובו ויעמוד כן כדי הילוך ארבע אמות ואח״כ ישלשלנו על כתפו. אבל אם
>   מתחילת הברכה מנחו מקופל על כתפו הוי ברכה לבטלה דהרי ליכא עיטוף. וגם
>   מצות ציצית לא קיים. והמוני עם מסתפקים בנשיקת הציצית פעמים ושלש ובזה
>   חושבים לפיים את הציצית על אשר לא טוב עשו לו. וראוי להוכיחם ולהשיב
>   מטעותם שלא יכשלו באיסור ברכה לבטלה. וד״ב.
>
> In Egypt the most common way is that one drapes all four ṣiṣioth to
>   their front and the tallit is folded on their neck. And it's
>   appropriate to inform them in their time of wrapping. He blesses and
>   wraps his head and most of his body in it and will stand up in the
>   space of four cubits and afterward will drape it over his shoulder.
>   But if from the beginning of the blessing he lays it folded on his
>   shoulder, then it is for nothing. And the commandment of ṣithṣith has
>   not been carried out. And the common people suffice in kissing the
>   ṣithṣith twice or three times and with that they think they make up to
>   the ṣithṣith for having mistreating it. They should be reproached and
>   their mistake should be clarified to prevent them from failing again
>   in the prohibition of saying a blessing in vain.

http://www.sefaria.org/Nehar_Misrayim.1.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all

Here is a photo that was brought back from my family from Cairo.

[image]

Comment: You brought this to prove that it is wrong?

Comment: Prove what is wrong?

Comment: It says so. "But if from the beginning of the blessing he lays it folded on his shoulder, then it is for nothing"

Comment: i believe that means that if it's already laying on his shoulder then the blessing is for nothing. That one should finish the blessing before laying it on his shoulder.

Comment: The common practice was to wear it in an inappropriate way. So there is a warning here at least to wear it the right way at the time of the blessing, so at least it will not be a blessing in vain. However, that doesn't change the fact that the entire time afterwards that it is worn inappropriately is not a kiyum of the Mitzvah.

Comment: I disagree completely with your reading of these words.

Comment: Also, it is obvious from context that these taaleisim are big enough. The taalesim in the question are too small. See the comment to Noach's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24045/discussion-between-aaron-and-user6591).

Comment: Also the mitzvah of tzitzis is different than eating matzah or something like that. Every moment one wears the taalis (properly:) he gets a kiyum schar. If someone wakes up towards the end of the day and remembers that they forgot to make the bracha, they make it then and there.