# Why do conservative Jews wear a tallit like a shawl?

Tags: tallit-gadol, conservative-judaism

I have had the opportunity to pray with conservative men several times both in orthodox and conservative synagogues. Inevitably the conservative men I prayed with wore their tallit like a shawl unlike the orthodox way which has the garment laying such that 2 of the fringes are in front of the person and two are behind. I would like to know if there is a reason **according to the conservative movement** as to why the tallit is worn in this fashion.

Example:

[image: random person I found on the internet]

Comment: FWIW this is also the minhag of some (Orthodox) German and Western Sephardic communities

Comment: This is a complicated issue since many halachic authorities hold that the main purpose is for the th talis to cover the body and not head(neck). Another issue is the size of the begged, many times the talis is not the right shiur. I honestly believe that they may not know the halacha,same question can be asked why do many wear their teffilin shel Rosh on the forehead (seen in orthodox shuls as well) ,simple answer, they are unaware of the halacha,unfortunately.

Comment: @joshk and Yemenites, if I’m not mistaken

Comment: After the atifa kahalacha after the beracha, you can do what you want with the talit

Comment: Seems like their Talisim are too narrow to wear in any way other than like a shawl.They even refer to them as prayer shawls.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Origin of Reform/Conservative "scarf" talleisim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/32095/origin-of-reform-conservative-scarf-talleisim)

Comment: @Fred that question seems to be referring to a different and specific article of clothing

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by user [Josh K](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16622/josh-k) in the comments, this is the way many communities in Western Europe don the tallit.

Since the Reform Movement was born out of Germany in the late 19th Century, they naturally had adopted this style of wearing the tallit. What we now call Conservative Judaism branched out from the German Reform community and therefore generally does it the same way.

Conservative Judaism doesn't have an official stance on how the tallit should be worn though, so nothing is stopping an individual or congregation from choosing to wear the tallit the more "Orthodox" way.